# Allowing new users to post comment on the original question when their question is closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion

When a new user ask a duplicate question, it most of the time ends up being closed as duplicate with a link to the original, usually with a comment saying "When you have earned enough reputation you'll be able to comment on other post etc.".

That's great for helping him finding an answer but what if the answers are out of date ? Or does not answer the question in a satisfying manner ? Then he/she find himself stuck without reputation and no way of getting an answer to his/her question.

I wonder why wouldn't we allow users that does not have sufficient reputation to post comment on the original question that made their question being closed as duplicate. That way they still can't comment on every posts (and still require 50 reputations before becoming more active on the site), but they can at least get an answer which is in my opinion the goal of Arqade. Even better they could *poke* an old and inactive question with out of date answers so the answerer can update their post, resulting in a better quality content on Arqade.

EDIT :

Regarding the abuse : Post a voluntary duplicate in order to be able to comment on the question.

I already had given it a tought : Even though that's an abuse resulting from this potential feature. I think it's a lot of work to go through just to be able to put comment on 1 question. If I wanted to make Arqade users/moderator/expert etc. lose time, I could simply open a lot of question (with multiple account), I could edit post forcing people to review them etc. I think there are many way that we can abuse Arqade system just to make people lose their time but this one seems like a lot of work (Askign a question > waiting for it to be closed > I can finally comment on 1 question). Gaining 50 reputation seems a lot faster, this become even more relevant if you allow only 1 comment (for example on the accepted answer).

Comment: So basically you can comment anywhere so long as you copy paste the text of the question you want to comment upon in advance?

Comment: @badp Yup, that's one flaw that I tought about, but again what prevent me from opening 100 questions and forcing you to close them as duplicate everytime. People who wants to abuse the system can always find a way, I think this is a nice small feature to help new user find the site more friendly. For now If that happened to me (question closed and not enough reputation) I would probably not come back to Arqade. Alos even allowing 1 comment on the original would be enough to request clarification or an update but not enough to vandalize the site.

Comment: @WizLiz - There is a threshold in place that if you ask too many downvoted/closed questions you get blocked from asking until you earn some positive rep etc

Comment: I think the 'poke' point is interesting, and could probably notify answer authors to take a look and see if their posts could be improved, but I think this might be taxing/difficult to implement. Maybe bump the original question to the front page upon having another question marked as duplicate of it?

Comment: @robotnik question blocks are not enabled on Arqade

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: A related answer: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5242/20456.  Essentially, we shouldn't be expecting more of new users, but expecting more of *ourselves*.  If it's a dupe, a new user can't do much, even if it doesn't help them.  What we can do, however, is request an update for them, and even bounty it.

Comment: @Frank That is actually a good point that didn't occur to me. Plus leaving a message "I requested an update on the original question so you can check back regularly if the answer has been updated" to the new user could help aswell. I'll do that from now on. Nonetheless, I think my idea is still stand though.